# Load a canvas from a main class - Java

Tags: java, java-canvas

I have a MyCanvas class that extends JComponent. On this canvas I have drawn a couple of things and has its own main method.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Graphics demo");
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(new Canvas0_1());
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);   }
```

How do I call to load the canvas from my program's other main method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but probably not what you need. If you insist just try:

```
class OtherClass {
   public static void main( String [] args ) {
       MyCanvas.main( args );
   }
}
```

And that's it.

I think it will be better if you  create an instance of your canvas and add it to another component and not use it directly from `main`